# MySQL or PHP to merge 2 tables to give me over table

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a competition where a user enters a team of 3 golfers chosen form a specific list. These entries are then stored in a table - entries with username,player1,player2,player3.

In a different table in the same database I have players results with each player have a player_name,round1score,round2score,round3score,round4score & totalscore.

I want to create a results set which adds the results of a users 3 players (their team) and sorts them with the lowest score for the combined 3 players.

I am having trouble combining the 2 tables and some people are saying the to merge them using PHP afterwards but not sure the best option.

Also I need to after the final round if there is a tie for 1st place make the team with the lowest round4score the top of the results.

Any help or advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: The part I'm stuck with is trying to order just by the round4 of any player because any of them could be the lowest. I'm not even sure if that's possible with SQL?

[code]SELECT t.name,
 t.player1, s1.to_par,
 t.player2, s2.to_par,
 t.player3, s3.to_par,
 s1.to_par+s2.to_par+s3.to_par as total_score

FROM pga_championship_2013 as t
 Left Join leaderboard_A as s1 On t.player1=s1.name
 Left Join leaderboard_A as s2 On t.player2=s2.name
 Left Join leaderboard_A as s3 On t.player3=s3.name

order by total_score asc [code]